# Creating a grid 16x26 in the console app using numbers and letters

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I'm trying to create in the console app a grid 16x26, like I said in the title, but I can't put even the numbers and the letters in the right place. Then I have to put unicode characters to create the grid like a map, using columns and lines. It's like a matrix that inside the letters and numbers goes the unicode characters.

Can someone help me, I'm new at this.

This is what I do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        char y;  
        int x, letra;

        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                if (j==0 && i==0 || i == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else if(j==0 && i > 1)
                {
                    letra = 65 + i;
                    y = Convert.ToChar(letra);
                    Console.Write(y + " ");
                }
                else if(i==0 && j > 1)
                {
                    x = 1 + j;
                    Console.WriteLine(" ", x);
                }
                else if(j % 2 == 0 && j != 0 && i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x + "");
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can you show us an example of the expected output, it would be much clearer. Thanks. We don't know where the "right" place is for all your data. P.S. Right now this code does not even compile.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to break down the problem into two tasks. First is to create and fill a 2D `char` array representation of your grid. You can do this hard-coded first (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays). The other task is to output the array to the console, cell by cell. By separating these two concerns, you can simplify the problems and develop/test/debug each job on its own. Trying to develop/debug both problems sandwiched together is an unnecessary headache.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(" ", x);` doesn't use `x` for anything.  If you want the value of `x` to appear in the output use either `Console.WriteLine(" {0}", x);` or `Console.WriteLine($" {x}");`, resulting in a new line with a space followed by the value of `x`.

Comment: I´m trying to create the grid without using arrays, only using "for" and "while"

Comment: @CopesLopes any particular reason for that? One of the normal uses of for and while loops is to loop through arrays! By not creating an array of data beforehand, you're mixing the process of creating the data with the process of displaying it. Normally, a good programmer would de-couple those two things into separate sections of the code. (This gives side benefits in a bigger application, e.g. the ability to display the same data in a different format, without changing the underlying data structure).

Comment: Anyway if you'd like further help, as I mentioned please show us what output you're expecting, because it's not immediately obvious precisely what the end result should be.

Comment: I'm still not clear about what you're asking for.  Edit your question and show a pre-formatted (monospaced) example of what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 2):

This little demo app may help you get where you're hoping to be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numberOfRows = 16;
    var numberOfCols = 26;
    for (var currentRow = 0; currentRow < numberOfRows; currentRow++)
    {
        for (var currentCol = 0; currentCol < numberOfCols; currentCol++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ({0:00}, {1:00})", currentRow, currentCol); //for each column in the current row, output some data (in this case, the coordinates of this cell formatted " (row, col)"
        }
        Console.WriteLine(); //once we've completed a row, write a new line to move down to the next row
    }
}
```

### Example Output

```
 (00, 00) (00, 01) (00, 02) (00, 03) (00, 04) (00, 05) (00, 06) (00, 07) (00, 08) (00, 09) (00, 10) (00, 11) (00, 12) (00, 13) (00, 14) (00, 15) (00, 16) (00, 17) (00, 18) (00, 19) (00, 20) (00, 21) (00, 22) (00, 23) (00, 24) (00, 25)
 (01, 00) (01, 01) (01, 02) (01, 03) (01, 04) (01, 05) (01, 06) (01, 07) (01, 08) (01, 09) (01, 10) (01, 11) (01, 12) (01, 13) (01, 14) (01, 15) (01, 16) (01, 17) (01, 18) (01, 19) (01, 20) (01, 21) (01, 22) (01, 23) (01, 24) (01, 25)
 (02, 00) (02, 01) (02, 02) (02, 03) (02, 04) (02, 05) (02, 06) (02, 07) (02, 08) (02, 09) (02, 10) (02, 11) (02, 12) (02, 13) (02, 14) (02, 15) (02, 16) (02, 17) (02, 18) (02, 19) (02, 20) (02, 21) (02, 22) (02, 23) (02, 24) (02, 25)
 (03, 00) (03, 01) (03, 02) (03, 03) (03, 04) (03, 05) (03, 06) (03, 07) (03, 08) (03, 09) (03, 10) (03, 11) (03, 12) (03, 13) (03, 14) (03, 15) (03, 16) (03, 17) (03, 18) (03, 19) (03, 20) (03, 21) (03, 22) (03, 23) (03, 24) (03, 25)
 (04, 00) (04, 01) (04, 02) (04, 03) (04, 04) (04, 05) (04, 06) (04, 07) (04, 08) (04, 09) (04, 10) (04, 11) (04, 12) (04, 13) (04, 14) (04, 15) (04, 16) (04, 17) (04, 18) (04, 19) (04, 20) (04, 21) (04, 22) (04, 23) (04, 24) (04, 25)
 (05, 00) (05, 01) (05, 02) (05, 03) (05, 04) (05, 05) (05, 06) (05, 07) (05, 08) (05, 09) (05, 10) (05, 11) (05, 12) (05, 13) (05, 14) (05, 15) (05, 16) (05, 17) (05, 18) (05, 19) (05, 20) (05, 21) (05, 22) (05, 23) (05, 24) (05, 25)
 (06, 00) (06, 01) (06, 02) (06, 03) (06, 04) (06, 05) (06, 06) (06, 07) (06, 08) (06, 09) (06, 10) (06, 11) (06, 12) (06, 13) (06, 14) (06, 15) (06, 16) (06, 17) (06, 18) (06, 19) (06, 20) (06, 21) (06, 22) (06, 23) (06, 24) (06, 25)
 (07, 00) (07, 01) (07, 02) (07, 03) (07, 04) (07, 05) (07, 06) (07, 07) (07, 08) (07, 09) (07, 10) (07, 11) (07, 12) (07, 13) (07, 14) (07, 15) (07, 16) (07, 17) (07, 18) (07, 19) (07, 20) (07, 21) (07, 22) (07, 23) (07, 24) (07, 25)
 (08, 00) (08, 01) (08, 02) (08, 03) (08, 04) (08, 05) (08, 06) (08, 07) (08, 08) (08, 09) (08, 10) (08, 11) (08, 12) (08, 13) (08, 14) (08, 15) (08, 16) (08, 17) (08, 18) (08, 19) (08, 20) (08, 21) (08, 22) (08, 23) (08, 24) (08, 25)
 (09, 00) (09, 01) (09, 02) (09, 03) (09, 04) (09, 05) (09, 06) (09, 07) (09, 08) (09, 09) (09, 10) (09, 11) (09, 12) (09, 13) (09, 14) (09, 15) (09, 16) (09, 17) (09, 18) (09, 19) (09, 20) (09, 21) (09, 22) (09, 23) (09, 24) (09, 25)
 (10, 00) (10, 01) (10, 02) (10, 03) (10, 04) (10, 05) (10, 06) (10, 07) (10, 08) (10, 09) (10, 10) (10, 11) (10, 12) (10, 13) (10, 14) (10, 15) (10, 16) (10, 17) (10, 18) (10, 19) (10, 20) (10, 21) (10, 22) (10, 23) (10, 24) (10, 25)
 (11, 00) (11, 01) (11, 02) (11, 03) (11, 04) (11, 05) (11, 06) (11, 07) (11, 08) (11, 09) (11, 10) (11, 11) (11, 12) (11, 13) (11, 14) (11, 15) (11, 16) (11, 17) (11, 18) (11, 19) (11, 20) (11, 21) (11, 22) (11, 23) (11, 24) (11, 25)
 (12, 00) (12, 01) (12, 02) (12, 03) (12, 04) (12, 05) (12, 06) (12, 07) (12, 08) (12, 09) (12, 10) (12, 11) (12, 12) (12, 13) (12, 14) (12, 15) (12, 16) (12, 17) (12, 18) (12, 19) (12, 20) (12, 21) (12, 22) (12, 23) (12, 24) (12, 25)
 (13, 00) (13, 01) (13, 02) (13, 03) (13, 04) (13, 05) (13, 06) (13, 07) (13, 08) (13, 09) (13, 10) (13, 11) (13, 12) (13, 13) (13, 14) (13, 15) (13, 16) (13, 17) (13, 18) (13, 19) (13, 20) (13, 21) (13, 22) (13, 23) (13, 24) (13, 25)
 (14, 00) (14, 01) (14, 02) (14, 03) (14, 04) (14, 05) (14, 06) (14, 07) (14, 08) (14, 09) (14, 10) (14, 11) (14, 12) (14, 13) (14, 14) (14, 15) (14, 16) (14, 17) (14, 18) (14, 19) (14, 20) (14, 21) (14, 22) (14, 23) (14, 24) (14, 25)
 (15, 00) (15, 01) (15, 02) (15, 03) (15, 04) (15, 05) (15, 06) (15, 07) (15, 08) (15, 09) (15, 10) (15, 11) (15, 12) (15, 13) (15, 14) (15, 15) (15, 16) (15, 17) (15, 18) (15, 19) (15, 20) (15, 21) (15, 22) (15, 23) (15, 24) (15, 25)
```

---

ps. Per ADyson's comment, if you first create an array then wanted to loop through the contents you'd only tweak the approach to output data slightly / like so:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new char[,] {{'A','B','C'}, {'D','E','F'}};
    for(var row=0; row<data.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for(var col=0; col<data.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            Console.Write(data[row,col]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

And you could populate the 2D array with code such as we'd used in the original post, only assigning to the array like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numberOfRows = 16;
    var numberOfCols = 26;
    var data = new char[numberOfRows, numberOfCols];
    for (var currentRow = 0; currentRow < numberOfRows; currentRow++)
    {
        for (var currentCol = 0; currentCol < numberOfCols; currentCol++)
        {
            data[currentRow, currentCol] = Convert.ToChar(65 + currentCol);
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use IEnumerable collections with lambda expressions and foreach loops like so:

```
void Main()
{

    //populate
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1,16).Select(x => 
        Enumerable.Range(1,26).Select(y => 
            Convert.ToChar(64 + y)
        )
    );

    //output one way
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nMethod 1\r\n");    
    foreach(var row in data)
    {
        foreach(var cell in row)
        {
            Console.Write(cell);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //or another
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nMethod 2\r\n");    
    data.ToList().ForEach(row => {
        row.ToList().ForEach(cell => 
            Console.Write(cell)
        ); 
        Console.WriteLine();
    });

    //or another approach convert each row from a collection of chars to strings separated by spaces, then join all the strings(rows) to one string separated by line breaks
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nMethod 3\r\n");    
    var output = string.Join("\r\n", data.Select(row => 
        string.Join(" ", row.Select(cell => 
            cell.ToString()
        ))
    )); 
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Hopefully some of these techniques help to give you some ideas.  If you need any explanations or have any issues implementing these for your scenario, please say in the comments and I'll provide additional help as needed.

---

NB: A good approach when tackling any issue is to break it down into steps, so if you're looking to draw a grid around your data, rather than having one method to do all the work, create different functions for each piece you're looking to achieve; i.e. one to format each row as you want it, another to put those rows into a table, etc.

Here's an example:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tb0zkV

```
void Main()
{

    //populate
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1,16).Select(x => 
        Enumerable.Range(1,26).Select(y => 
            Convert.ToChar(64 + y)
        )
    );
    //display
    Console.WriteLine(data.ToTableFormatString());
}

public static class TableCreationExtension
{

    //converts the output of ToTableFormat to a single string
    public static string ToTableFormatString(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> rows) =>
        string.Join("\r\n", rows.ToTableFormat());

    /* 
        calls other methods to convert the data to the inner table format, then surrounds with a double edged box
        ╔═════╗
        ║inner║
        ║table║
        ║goes ║ 
        ║here ║
        ╚═════╝
        info on required characters here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character           
    */
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToTableFormat(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> rows)
    {
        var rowsAsStrings = rows.ToInnerTableFormat();
        var rowLength = rowsAsStrings.First().Length; //assume that all rows are the same length, so the length of the first equals the length of all others
        //first row of box
        yield return string.Format("╔{0}╗", new string('═', rowLength));
        //each row within the box
        foreach(var row in rowsAsStrings)
        {
            yield return string.Format("║{0}║", row);
        }
        //last row of box
        yield return string.Format("╚{0}╝", new string('═', rowLength));
    }

    /*
        calls other methods to convert each row into a formatted string
        Adds a separator between each row.

        each
        ---------
        row
        ---------
        separated
    */
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToInnerTableFormat(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> rows)
    {
        bool returnInnerLine = false;
        int rowLength = 0; //assume all rows are the same length
        foreach(var row in rows)
        {
            var formattedRow = row.ToFormattedRow();
            if (returnInnerLine)
            {
                yield return new string('-', rowLength); //returns a line of -s the same length as a row for a between-row separator
            }
            else
            {
                returnInnerLine = true;
                rowLength = formattedRow.Length;
            }
            yield return formattedRow;
        }
    }

    //converts `'A', 'B', 'C'` to "A|B|C" 
    public static string ToFormattedRow(this IEnumerable<char> cellsInRow) =>
        string.Join("|", cellsInRow.Select(c => c.ToString()));
}
```

Output

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
¦---------------------------------------------------¦
¦A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z¦
+---------------------------------------------------+
```